# UIPinchGestureRecognizer - Suppress 'close pinch' detection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using the UIPinchRecognizer and an open pinch to detect when someone 'pulls apart' a sprite in a Box2D world.

The problem is that when you drag two items toward each other it detects this as a close pinch and breaks all my touchjoints and the movement of the box2d objects.

I've tried to split my problem into two questions - the question you're reading now: is it is possible to suppress the close pinch, and if that's not possible: [how to detect an open pinch myself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10185556/459116).

I need to either suppress the detection of close pinches or write my own open pinch detection.

I tried returning from the pinch gesture method on an open pinch like this:

```
if (pinch.velocity < 0) {
    //close pinch
    return;
}
```

but it doesn't work because it still breaks the touch joints / box2d objects.

**Could you help me solve this problem by suppressing the detection of close pinches?**

Comment: This "dragging two items toward each other" action that your pinch recognizer is interfering with -- is that also implemented via gesture recognizer? If so, you should look into setting up explicit dependencies between recognizers with `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` or the delegate method `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`.

Comment: Dragging two objects toward one another is achieved with box2d mouse joints, not a gesture recognizer - but it is interpreted by the uipinchgesturerecognizer as a pinch. The only gesture recognizer I'm using is the pinch.

Comment: Why doesn't the solution you attempted work?  Is pinch.velocity not less than zero when you do a close pinch?

Comment: No it is - but when the pinchgesturerecognizer is triggered it invalidates all my mouse joints. This is fine for an open pinch - because it's doing its intended function, but not for close pinches because anytime two items are dragged toward one another the touches are captured by the pinchgesturerecognizer and I can't get them back. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to check this on a device, but I think that this has fixed it:

```
//Multitouch / pinch?
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchGesture:)];
pinchRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; //This fixes it because it stops the mouse joints getting broken. 

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
[UIPinchGestureRecognizer release];
```

with this in the pinchGesture method:

```
if(pinch.velocity <0 ){
    return;
}
```